# Dynamically fetch and compile a template with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to fetch an svg from a remote and bring it to life by compiling it. With 'bring to life' I mean selecting some of it's elements by class and dynamically append a list of components into it.

Right now I just use `<div v-html="svg"/>` and my component looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    svg: '',
  }
},
async created() {
  let res = await axios.get(mySvgSrc)
  this.svg = res.data
}
```

But this doesn't allow me to bring it to life by inserting elements with vue bindings.

Thus, I would like to use dynamic components like `<component :is="compName"></component>` so after fetching my svg, use the result as template. Example [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3kpd20/1/).

```
data() {
  return {
    compName: 'someDefaultComponent',
  }
},
async created() {
  let res = await axios.get(mySvgSrc)
  Vue.component('svgComponent', { template: res.data })
  this.compName = 'svgComponent' 
}
```

However, nuxt keeps complaining about it not being able to compile it:

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
>   template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
>   into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

What should I do?

1) Somehow convert the svg (string) template into a render function after fetching it?

2) Use the compiler-included build? (rather not, but if so: how does that work?)

I have the feeling that I need option 2) in order to do option 1).

#### EDIT

Just found [v-runtime-template](https://alligator.io/vuejs/v-runtime-template/), not sure if it's the vue way-to-go though...

Answer (score 11):

You need to change Vue build.
Add this string:

```
config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
```

to nuxt.config.js
here:

```
build: {
  /*
  ** You can extend webpack config here
  */
  extend(config, ctx) {
    config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
```

Comment: Why does this work? What is `config.resolve.alias` and `vue/dist/vue.common`?

Comment: You can read about it here:
https://gist.github.com/anchal20/f2ac9807263e106c1308f7143df1cf09#file-vuejs-builds-explained