# Vuejs how to use dynamical template in component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
const CustomComponent = {
  props: ['index'],
  template: `<span>I am a custom component: {{ index }}</span>`
};

const UserInputResult = {
  components: {
    CustomComponent
  },
  props: ['templateString'],
  template: `<section v-html="templateString"></section>` 
}

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data(){
      return {
         userInput: 'user input example [:component-1]'
      }
   },
   components: {
      UserInputResult
   },
   methods: {
      generateTemplate(){
         let raw = this.userInput;
         if (!!raw && raw.match(/\[\:component\-\d+\]/g)) {
            let components = [...raw.match(/\[\:component\-\d+\]/g)];
            components.forEach(component => {
               raw = raw.replace(component, `<custom-component :index="${component.match(/\d+/)[0]}"></custom-component>`);
            });             
         }
         return raw;
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="userInput"></textarea>
  <user-input-result :template-string="generateTemplate()">
</div>
```

I want to render a custom component which has a dynamical template base on user input.

when user input a specific string (`[:component-1]`), it will be render as a component (`CustomComponent`)

how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for anyone help!

Comment: It seems to be a recursive dynamic component rendering. Then maybe using the render method would be the way to go. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html
Alternativly we could use the `<component :is="type">` approach.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: @Kunukn sorry for my poor expression, you may misunderstand what I say. It doesn't matter about recursive rendering, what really matter is how to render the child component correctly base on the user's input

Comment: Check this out https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamically-compile-router-link/7410/7, it's a working demo compile a html text `router-link` into a fully functional `<router-link>`, I think it should be what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using `Vue.complie`

according to [dynamically-fetch-and-compile-a-template-with-nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261646/10519069)

```js
const UserInputResult = {
  props: ['templateString'],
  render(h){
    return h({
      components: {
        CustomComponent
      },
      template: `<section>${this.templateString}</section>`
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `v-slot`
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Example:
Parent:

```
<child-component v-html="myTemplate">
    <span>From parent</span>
</child-component>
```

Child:

```
<div>
    <v-slot></v-slot> //Will output "<span>From parent</span>"
</div>
```

**Added more explaination
You can then condition check and update `myTemplate` to your desired template. `"<span>From parent</span>"` is just there for explanation on how slot works.

---

updated by the questioner

```js
const CustomComponent = {
  props: ['index'],
  template: `<span>I am a custom component: {{ index }}</span>`
};

const UserInputResult = {
  template: `<section><slot></slot></section>` 
}

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data(){
      return {
         userInput: 'user input example [:component-1]'
      }
   },
   components: {
      UserInputResult,
      CustomComponent
   },
   methods: {
      generateTemplate(){
         let raw = this.userInput;
         if (!!raw && raw.match(/\[\:component\-\d+\]/g)) {
            let components = [...raw.match(/\[\:component\-\d+\]/g)];
            components.forEach(component => {
               raw = raw.replace(component, `<custom-component :index="${component.match(/\d+/)[0]}"></custom-component>`);
            });             
         }
         return raw;
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="userInput"></textarea>
  <user-input-result>
    {{ generateTemplate() }} 
  </user-input-result>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for my poor expression. The issue is about how to render the template string which include custom vue component base on user input inside, not for the `v-slot`. I updated your reply with an example of `v-slot` version

Comment: @DengSihan Do you mean "to render custom component dynamically based on user input"? If that's the case does <component :is> solve your problem ? That is exactly how to render child component dynamically based on user input.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out by using `Vue.complie()`